# the state inside hooks are not updated for first time on form submit in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I was trying to implement contactUS form in react using hooks.Contact us form is placed inside hooks.When I first submit the form the state in hooks are not updated ,when I click 2nd time states are set .and  I am returning state to class component there api call are made.

//contactushook.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ContactUshook = ({ parentCallBack }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setData({ name: document.getElementById('name').value, email: document.getElementById('email').value, message: document.getElementById('message').value });

        console.log(data);
        parentCallBack(data);
    }

    return <React.Fragment>
        <div className="form-holder">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="enter the name"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter the email"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </React.Fragment >

}

export default ContactUshook;
```

//contactus.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ContactUshook from './hooks/contactushook';
import '../contactUs/contactus.css';
class ContactComponent extends Component {

    onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log('in onsubmit');
        console.log(data);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>hook</h4>
                <ContactUshook parentCallBack={this.onSubmit}></ContactUshook>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactComponent;
```

Comment: Its called "controlled component". You don't want the DOM to handle the values, but instead react itself, or you need to use refs. [controlled components - Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) [Refs - Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs)

Answer (score 1):

Stop using document queries and start using state instead!

Your ContactUshook component should look like this:

```
const ContactUshook = ({ parentCallBack }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ name: '', email: '', message: '' });

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        event.preventDefault();
        parentCallBack(data);
    }

    const handleChange = (event, field) => {
        const newData = { ...data };
        newData[field] = event.target.value;
        setData(newData);
    }

    return (
        <div className="form-holder">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <input 
                        id="name" 
                        type="text" 
                        value={data.name}
                        placeholder="enter the name" 
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,'name')} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input 
                        id="email" 
                        type="email" 
                        value={data.email} 
                        placeholder="enter the email" 
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,'email')} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea 
                        id="message" 
                        value={data.message} 
                        placeholder="Type message here" 
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,'message')} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I am trying your code but i get error at const newData = ...data